# Script to run commands as soon as a key is hit

Tags: bash, shell-script

I would like to make a repeating function in bash, that runs the same
three commands every time any key is pressed.

In Windows, I can do this by having the pause command in an infinite loop
in a batch file, which works fine for my needs.

Most *nix distros don't have a pause command equivalent, and `read
-p` is not functioning the way I would like.

What is the best way to accomplish what I need? Additionally, would it
be possible to have a different command (for cleanup) executed when a
certain key combination (say <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>) is input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming bash, the `read` option `-N` may be useful:

```
  -N nchars return only after reading exactly NCHARS characters, unless
            EOF is encountered or read times out, ignoring any delimiter
```

If you use `read -N 1 x`, it will return as soon as a character is
entered, without waiting for a newline.

Regarding the second part of your question, hitting
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> sends the INT signal to your script;
intercepting that is a simple matter of catching that signal.

An example putting it all together:

```
trap 'echo special command' INT

while read -N 1 foo; do
    echo normal command
done
```

And a sample interaction (I hit <kbd>x</kbd> twice, and then
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> once):

```
xnormal command
xnormal command
^Cspecial command
```

(Note that this script will be annoying to exit; one way would be to
stop it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> and then killing the job.)

Comment: (1) You say "I hit ⌧ twice", but your output seems to show three.  (2) Just as a matter of presentation, it seems a little confusing that you're using the same letter as the *name* of the variable *and* the *value* that you're assigning to it.

Comment: @G-Man, I edited my post to address both of your remarks. Thanks for being so sharp-eyed!

Comment: Thanks, this is really helping me understand and learn scripting. Now, where you have 'echo special command', could this be a call to a function?

Comment: Yes, the calls to `echo` are placeholders, you can put whatever calls you want instead of them.